# How do I access datasources in ordinary groovy classes in Grails 3?

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

I'm trying to run sql-code from inside an ordinary Groovy class (no service).
In Grails 2 I could access a datasource by doing this:

```
 public GroovyClass() {
    def ctx = ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
    def dataSource = ctx.getBean('dataSource')
    sql = new Sql(dataSource)
 }
```

After migrating to Grails 3.3.8 the code no longer works. What is the correct method in Grails 3.3.8?

Comment: The accepted answer below is a bad idea.  I would not advocate for doing that.  The right answer requires knowing more about the context from which you are interacting with this groovy class.  Are you interacting with it from a controller?  A service?  BootStrap?  Something else?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown From a Grails service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Hollywood Principle" says "Don't call us, we will call you" and that is what dependency injection is about.  In your case, don't go get the `dataSource`, have the `dataSource` given to you.

There are a number of ways to do that.  See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/asdudemo.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/asdudemo/blob/master/src/main/groovy/ascudemo/helpers/FirstGroovyClass.groovy

```
// src/main/groovy/ascudemo/FirstGroovyClass.groovy
package ascudemo.helpers

import groovy.sql.Sql
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean

import javax.sql.DataSource

@Slf4j
class FirstGroovyClass implements InitializingBean {
    DataSource dataSource
    Sql sql

    void logSomeInfo() {
        // both have been initialized
        log.debug "dataSource: ${dataSource}"
        log.debug "sql: ${sql}"
    }

    @Override
    void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/asdudemo/blob/master/src/main/groovy/ascudemo/helpers/SecondGroovyClass.groovy

```
// src/main/groovy/ascudemo/SecondGroovyClass.groovy
package ascudemo.helpers

import groovy.sql.Sql
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct
import javax.sql.DataSource

@Slf4j
class SecondGroovyClass {
    DataSource dataSource
    Sql sql

    void logSomeInfo() {
        // both have been initialized
        log.debug "dataSource: ${dataSource}"
        log.debug "sql: ${sql}"
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void initSql() throws Exception {
        sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/asdudemo/blob/master/src/main/groovy/ascudemo/helpers/ThirdGroovyClass.groovy

```
// src/main/groovy/ascudemo/SecondGroovyClass.groovy
package ascudemo.helpers

import groovy.sql.Sql
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware

import javax.sql.DataSource

@Slf4j
class ThirdGroovyClass implements ApplicationContextAware {
    Sql sql

    void logSomeInfo() {
        // sql been initialized
        log.debug "sql: ${sql}"
    }

    @Override
    void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        DataSource dataSource = applicationContext.getBean('dataSource', DataSource)
        sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/asdudemo/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/ascudemo/DemoController.groovy

```
// grails-app/controllers/ascudemo/DemoController.groovy
package ascudemo

class DemoController {

    SomeService someService

    def index() {
        someService.logSomeInfo()
        render 'Success'
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/asdudemo/blob/master/grails-app/services/ascudemo/SomeService.groovy

```
// grails-app/services/ascudemo/SomeService.groovy
package ascudemo

import ascudemo.helpers.FirstGroovyClass
import ascudemo.helpers.SecondGroovyClass
import ascudemo.helpers.ThirdGroovyClass

class SomeService {

    FirstGroovyClass firstGroovyBean
    SecondGroovyClass secondGroovyBean
    ThirdGroovyClass thirdGroovyBean

    def logSomeInfo() {
        firstGroovyBean.logSomeInfo()
        secondGroovyBean.logSomeInfo()
        thirdGroovyBean.logSomeInfo()
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/asdudemo/blob/master/grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy

```
// grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy
import ascudemo.helpers.FirstGroovyClass
import ascudemo.helpers.SecondGroovyClass
import ascudemo.helpers.ThirdGroovyClass

beans = {
    // demonstrates one approach
    firstGroovyBean(FirstGroovyClass) { bean ->
        bean.autowire = 'byName'
    }

    // demonstrates another approach
    secondGroovyBean(SecondGroovyClass) { bean ->
        bean.autowire = 'byName'
    }

    // demonstrates a third approach
    thirdGroovyBean ThirdGroovyClass
}
```

Run the app and send a request to http://localhost:8080/demo/ and that will verify that all 3 approaches worked.

There are other ways to do this but I hope that one of the above will be helpful to you.

Best of luck!

Comment: That may look more complicated than it is, in part because there are 3 different solutions shown above.  All you are really doing is adding an instance of your class to the Spring application context (in `resources.groovy`) so it can be subjected to DI and then injecting that bean wherever you want to use it.  In the example above that is `SomeService`.

Comment: Appreciate the thorough answer, very helpful and educational.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it seems to give the datasource

```
def ds = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('dataSource')
println "DataSource: ${ds}"  ---> DataSource: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy@5e91ade8
```

Didn't try any operations on it, but that looks right.

Comment: Using `Holders` to gain access to beans is discouraged.